# DateListPlot: Highs and Lows

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have this data:

```
data =
  {{{2015, 3, 25}, 130}, {{2015, 3, 26}, 132}, {{2015, 3, 27}, 
    132}, {{2015, 3, 30}, 133}, {{2015, 3, 31}, 132}, {{2015, 4, 1}, 
    131}, {{2015, 4, 2}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 3}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 6}, 
    131}, {{2015, 4, 7}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 8}, 129}, {{2015, 4, 9}, 
    132}, {{2015, 4, 10}, 133}, {{2015, 4, 13}, 132}, {{2015, 4, 14}, 
    131}, {{2015, 4, 15}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 16}, 128}, {{2015, 4, 17}, 
    125}, {{2015, 4, 20}, 127}, {{2015, 4, 21}, 127}};
```

I want to produce with `DateListPlot` an image almost like this one:

[image]

Almost? If there are more than one maxima or minima only the first point should be plotted.

In reality my data is much longer.

What could an elegant and efficient answer look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps a bit more elegant than Sjoerd's approach:

```
data = Sort @ data;   (* address Sjoerd's concern *)

pts = {
   data,
   MinimalBy[data, Last, 1],
   MaximalBy[data, Last, 1]
 };

DateListPlot[pts,
  Joined    -> {True, False, False}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Green}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly a highly fashionable answer :)

Comment: Does this guarantee that you always pick the first peak if there are ties and `data`   isn't ordered?

Comment: @Sjoerd The `data` appeared to be ordered.  `Sort` it if it is not.

Comment: That's what I did already. The data given is just an example. Just wanted to point out that you have an implicit and unwarranted assumption in your approach.

Comment: @Sjoerd I added a sort to my code.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't aimed for efficiency or elegance but for 'straightforwardness'

```
data = Sort@data; (* just to make sure the dates are always sorted *)

max = Max@data[[All, 2]];
min = Min@data[[All, 2]];
maxPos = FirstPosition[data[[All, 2]], max] // First;
minPos = FirstPosition[data[[All, 2]], min] // First;

maxPlotPos = MapAt[AbsoluteTime, data[[maxPos]], 1];
minPlotPos = MapAt[AbsoluteTime, data[[minPos]], 1];

DateListPlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[.02], Point@maxPlotPos, Red, Point@minPlotPos}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Lest we forget the old-fashined ways:

```
extremes=data[[Ordering[# data[[All,2]],1][[1]]&/@{-1,1}]];

DateListPlot[{data,##&@@(List/@extremes)},
 Joined -> {True,False,False}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 PlotStyle -> {Gray,Red, Green}, PlotLegends -> {"data", "max","min"}]
```

[image]

Note: If `data` is not sorted, we need to sort it first (*thanks: @Sjoerd *):

```
data = data[[Ordering[data]]];
extremes = data[[Ordering[# data[[All, 2]], 1][[1]] & /@ {-1, 1}]];
```

Comment: I have always liked your styles: `##&@@` is extremely nice  :)

Comment: Thank you @eldo. I think i learned it from Mr.W.

Comment: Does this guarantee that you always pick the first peak if there are ties and `data`   isn't ordered?

Comment: Yes, I am fairly sure I am the one who infected you. :o)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, good point; it doesn't. So, that gives us another chance to use `Ordering`:)

Answer (score 3):

Do you care about maxima and minima or peaks? If peaks then you could use `FindPeaks` but this is only available for M10+. Note also that `FindPeaks` only handles regularly spaced `TimeSeries` - hence the use of `TemporalRegularity`:

```
data = TimeSeries[{{{2015, 3, 25}, 130}, {{2015, 3, 26}, 
 132}, {{2015, 3, 27}, 132}, {{2015, 3, 30}, 133}, {{2015, 3, 31},
  132}, {{2015, 4, 1}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 2}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 3}, 
 131}, {{2015, 4, 6}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 7}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 8}, 
 129}, {{2015, 4, 9}, 132}, {{2015, 4, 10}, 133}, {{2015, 4, 13}, 
 132}, {{2015, 4, 14}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 15}, 131}, {{2015, 4, 16},
  128}, {{2015, 4, 17}, 125}, {{2015, 4, 20}, 
 127}, {{2015, 4, 21}, 127}}, TemporalRegularity -> True];
DateListPlot[{data, FindPeaks[data], 
TimeSeriesMap[#*-1 &, FindPeaks[TimeSeriesMap[#*-1 &, data]]]}, 
Joined -> {True, False, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is expressly not what eldo requested but since you just introduced me to `TemporalRegularity` here is my +1.

Comment: Right, I was not looking for peaks.+1 for the reason given by wiz. I will play       with `TemporalRegularity` tomorrow :)

Comment: @eldo I did push the `Almost?` in your question a bit far, but I decided to try and break 1000 before midnight and needed all the awkwardly placed fruit I could find. Strange to see `TemporalRegularity` is only mentioned three times on MMA.SE, glad to have given you something to play with though.

Comment: Well, you hit it !!!