# Flattening of Matrix rows

Tags: list-manipulation

It's got to be easy, but I can't come up with a general solution.

```
m = {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {{5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}}, {4, 14, 15, 1}};
```

What I'm trying to obtain:

```
m = {16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1}};
```

These 'groups of rows' can show at many places, so `FlattenAt` solution is not enough. I'd really like to use a `Flatten` or an `ArrayFlatten` solution.

Comment: I recommend you give an *example* list `m` that shows `FlattenAt[m,1]` does not work, rather than describing cases in which it will not work.

Comment: You're right. Edited

Comment: Are the end result all same length like example? Then something as simple as `Partition[Flatten[m], 4]` will be most efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "Rows" are all same length (here 4):

```
m = {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {{5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}}, {4, 14, 15, 1}};

Partition[Flatten[m], 4]

(* {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1}} *)
```

Will be *much* more efficient...

Comment: Ooh that's a nice answer! Thanks !

Comment: @Literal: Glad to help. Don't forget to pick & check an answer, and vote on *all* that were useful...

Comment: @rasher Don't forget to vote for this earlier incarnation of your answer: [(20340)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20340/121) (not mine)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done

Comment: @ciao What is going on with your account?  Please tell me you aren't leaving Stack Exchange? :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, though I'm quite puzzled why this comment notification showed up on my *math* account. I recall you have my e-mail, feel free to use it.

Comment: @ciao I am afraid I have forgotten it.  If you have mine please email me.  If not please let us connect before your departure.

Comment: @ciao There is a gmail account attached to your profile.  Unless you state otherwise I shall take the above comment as permission to contact you via that address.

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = {{{16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1},
       {{a, b, c}, {v, x, y}}};

mat2 = MapAt[## & @@ # &, mat, Position[mat, {{__}, {__}}]]
(* {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1}, 
    {a, b, c}, {v, x, y}} *)

mat3 = FlattenAt[mat, Position[mat, {{__}, {__}}]]
(* {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1}, 
    {a, b, c}, {v, x, y}} *)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it would have been easier to achieve it (involving a single function)

Comment: I swear, BlankNullSequence must have compromising photos of you, as much as you use it ;-)   +1 for patterny prettiness!

Comment: thank you @rasher. Source:  [BlankNullSequence infection](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80627/125) :)

Comment: Mr. 70K, please try a little harder to help me find duplicates; I know you have seen [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20319/121).  You're #2 on the site now and I need all the help I can get!

Comment: Heard you @Mr.W.  What keywords did you use  to get the link ([this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20319/121))?

Comment: I believe I searched for Partition and Flatten, remembering an earlier answer with that solution.  Admittedly this was based on an answer that was posted after yours.  Rereading my comment from yesterday it sounds like I was scolding you and that was surely not my intent.  Rather I fear that I see the site becoming increasingly disorganized as the total number of questions grows and an increasing amount of effort spent on answering questions that have already been answered.  I'm not sure how to help that and it makes me a little agitated.  Sorry.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, not to worry -- I didn't take it that way. I do share your concern .Many questions trigger a seen-that-somewhere  feeling, and finding a relevant link is getting increasingly more difficult - sometimes I spend hours searching for my own answers, and often without success. I agree we need more effort to search but without accompanied efforts to make the search engine more effective it will be difficult to avoid the vicious spiral.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
m = {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {{5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}}, {4, 14, 15, 1}};
```

We could use `Sequence` to "unwrap" lists of depth 3:

```
Apply[Sequence, m, {-3}]

(* {{16, 2, 3, 13}, {5, 11, 10, 8}, {9, 7, 6, 12}, {4, 14, 15, 1}} *)
```

Equivalently:

```
Apply[##&, m, {-3}]
```

Direct replacement of nested lists can work too:

```
Replace[m, {x:_List...} :> x, {1}]
```

These approaches will work on variable-length rows:

```
m2 = {{1, 2}, {{3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}, {9, 10, 11}, {{12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16}}};

Apply[##&, m2, {-3}]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}, {16}} *)
```

If the nesting is variable-depth, we can use `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
m3 = {{1, 2}, {{3, 4}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{{9, 10}}, {11, 12}}}};

Scan[Sow, m3, {-2}] // Reap // #[[2, 1]] &

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}} *)
```